# Change firefox page setup/scale using javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, printing, scale

How can I change firefox page scale using javascript?

How can I change firefox page scale (File/ Page setup/ Scale) using javascript, to change print size?

I've tried following code but does not work!

document.body.style.transform='scale(0.80)'

This code changes page scale in browser(firefox) but page scale in page setup menu, just changes print size.